# how to use unnamed parameters?

Tags: solidity

Solidity allows for [unnamed function params](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=anonymous#omitted-function-parameter-names), how to use them?

```
contract C {

 // omitted parameters
 function func(uint k, uint ) returns(uint) {
    return k;
 }

}
```

Comment: +1 for bringing up an interesting topic unused method parameter, for return parameter see my answer.

Comment: Frankly I suspect it is only a sideeffect for creating the unnamed return parameter. It was easier to say in this BNF both are a parameter and I allow also input parameter but they will go to dev/null... If not I will be happy to know a new feature...

Answer (score 3):

I could answer the `returns` parameter anonymity.It takes a  return statement to return some value from the function for not having a parameter name.

Whereas having a named parameter in the `returns`, we don't need a return statement.Whatever value is assigned to the named parameter in the return argument would be returned at the end of the function execution automatically.

```
function func(uint k, uint ) returns(uint myValue) {
  myValue=404;
}
```

404 is returned automatically without even having a return statement. I hope it helps partially

Answer (score 0):

**Increases readability.**

If your logic doesn't require some of the parameters, omit naming those parameters to make it obvious that your logic doesn't depend on them.