# In Solidity how to use unnamed function parameters?

Tags: solidity

just wanted to know that in Solidity we can give function parameters without any name by just giving type, but how can we use them inside a function:

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.7.1;

contract demo{
    
function myFunction1(int, int8, int) public{
        // now ho to use these received parameters
    }
}
```

This question is already asked [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6793/how-to-use-unnamed-parameters) but no reasonable answer is given. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `how can we use them inside a function` - you're obviously going to write code inside that function, so start by giving a name to each one of those unnamed parameters. In other words, the answer to "how to use unnamed parameters" is "by naming them"!!!

Answer (score 9):

You can't access them with Solidity. You may be able to use inline assembly to do it, but there is no point really, and you should just give them a name if you want to use them in the function.

There are a few use cases for unnamed parameters. They can be useful if you have a function that overrides another function, but you only need certain parameters from that function. They are also often used for return parameters. For example:

```
interface A {
  function doSomething (uint256 a, uint256 b) external returns (uint256);
}

contract B is A {
  function doSomething(uint256, uint256 b) override external returns (uint256) {
    return b;
  }
}
```

Since it's not accessing `a`, you can omit the name in the override function. It also returns directly in the function, so there is no need to name the return parameter, like:

```
contract B is A {
  function doSomething(uint256, uint256 b) override external returns (uint256 c) {
    c = b;
  }
}
```

This can be useful or not, depending on your use case. Removing the parameter altogether would result in a different function signature, and in this case a compiler error since the function does not implement the interface properly.