# Solidity optional parameters patterns

Tags: solidity

I know that you can't define optional parameters in solidity, but what are the best patterns to imitate it? The only way I know it is function overloading but sometimes it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unnamed parameters (function parameters without any name) in Solidity. Unnamed parameters can be useful if you have a function that overrides another function (as in inheritance), but you only need certain parameters from that function. They are also often used for return parameters.

See:

[In Solidity how to use unnamed function parameters?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87533/in-solidity-how-to-use-unnamed-function-parameters)